# contents of doctype in html

Tags: html, doctype

I dont understand the doctype in html.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Can you please explain what does each thing mean here.

Comment: Have you seen the HTML 5 doctype? It is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">


!DOCTYPE - The document type declaration
HTML - The root element is HTML, the type of document is HTML
PUBLIC - Availability - this is a public doctype
"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" - A formal identifier
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" - URI, here it is the location of the DTD
```

There is a further breakdown on [about.com](http://webdesign.about.com/od/dtds/qt/tipdoctype.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The parts of that doctype are:

```
Root element:             HTML
DTD type:                 PUBLIC
Formal Public Identifier: "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
DTD URL:                  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

However, you don't really have to know what it all means. Just pick one of the doctype declarations from [W3C's recommended list of doctype declarations](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).